# K8s comunicacion entre pods arquitectura serviceip

Tags: spring, cloud, arquitectura, kubernetes

Tengo un problema de comunicación entre Tipo de servicio: NodePort y Tipo de servicio: ClusterIp en kubernetes. el error es 404 no encontrado Además, he verificado que el nombre del servicio es igual al nombre del punto final y ambos se implementan en el mismo clúster y espacio de nombres, pero por alguna razón no puede llegar. Lo que intento hacer es establecer una arquitectura basada en ServiceIp y que se comunique con diferentes microservicios de back-end. La ayuda es urgente y muchas gracias.

ServiceIp:

apiVersion: tipo v1: metadatos del servicio: nombre: gatewaykubernetes etiquetas: aplicación: gatewaykubernetes especificación: tipo: NodePort selector: aplicación: gatewaykubernetes puertos: - nombre: puerto http: 8888 nodePort: 32200 targetPort: http

Tipo de servicio ClusterIp:

apiVersion: v1 kind: metadatos del servicio: nombre: registro etiquetas: aplicación: especificación de registro: selector: aplicación: puertos de registro: - nombre: puerto http: 9082

Kubectl get svc namespace

gatewaykubernetes 10.103.255.36 8888: 32200 / TCP 31m

grabar 10,101.53,120 9082 / TCP 44d

consultas generales 10,111,199.16 9080 / TCP 44d

Mi idea es que a través de gatewaykubernetes tenga acceso a los servicios de registro y consulta general.

Yo uso: dependencias de Spring-Cloud-Kubernetes, Spring-Cloud-Kubernetes-discovery, Spring-Cloud-starter-gateway, Spring-boot-starter-webflux, Spring-Cloud-starter-kubernetes, Spring-Cloud-starter-gateway , spring-cloud-kubernetes-config, spring-boot-starter-actuator

Answer (score 0):

buenos días encontré una solución en mi caso y es file identetion app.yml, donde las propiedades pueden alinearse:

```
 **kubernetes**:
   config:
     name: default-name
     namespace: default-namespace
     sources:
      - name: desarrollo-mtm
      - namespace: desarrollo-mtm

     enableApi: true

**reload**:
  enabled: true
  mode: polling
  period: 5000
**discovery:**
  serviceLabels:
    spring-boot: true
  filter: "metadata.labels['app']"
```

la propiedad de Kubernetes debe estar alineada con reaload y discovery para que funcione y no este asi

**kubernetes**:
       config:
         name: default-name
         namespace: default-namespace
         sources:
          - name: desarrollo-mtm
          - namespace: desarrollo-mtm

```
     enableApi: true

**reload**:
  enabled: true
  mode: polling
  period: 5000
**discovery:**
  serviceLabels:
    spring-boot: true
  filter: "metadata.labels['app']"
```

gracias.